# Ensure no duplicates save MySql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table in mySql that looks like this

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start_of_week | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_of_week   | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| weekday       | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to ensure that no duplicate is saved into it. I know I could do a select statement before something like this

```
"select count(*) from Table where start_of_week = %s and end_of_week = %s and weekday = %s", (start_date, end_date, a_weekday)
```

And if that returns 0, then there is no item, exactly the same so save it. But I was wondering if there is another way, possibly a better way to ensure no duplicates are saved. By the way I am using python to save to the database, but I was wondering if there is a way in the set up of the table to accomplish this? Or a different check to perform in python?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a composite key on all of the columns in the table and then the DB would not allow duplicates, but that is not recommended due to issues you could run into with clustered index size and slow performance.

What you would do is create a surrogate key which could be a md5 hash of each row and then make that a primary key or composite key with the incremental primary key.

You can use hashlib to generate an md5 hash of the record and then store that in the md5 column in your table. Then make that the primary key. If you try to insert a duplicate row, it will have the same md5 value and the database will give you an error since it is a duplicate key.

See here on how to use hashlib
https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(start_of_week) # these would be the values you are storing in the corresponding rows of the table
m.update(end_of_week)
m.update(weekday)
m.digest()
```

Then store m.digest() into the md5 column.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on how to do this?

Comment: okay but I would always have `m.update("start date") m.update("end date") m.update("weekday")`, because that would always generate the same has inside the `update()` I would put the actual string that I am saving to the database correct?

Comment: Those are just placeholder strings, you would put the corresponding variables with your values there, not the strings I have. I will edit that as well to be more clear.

Comment: Great, and last thing is the `md5` column a varchar? and I am going to key my regular auto-incremting primary `id` key so how do i make `md5` a composite key? Or can I just make the `md5` column unique?

Comment: Md5 is 32 byte string so char(32) should be fine. You can add a unique constraint to the md5 column or make it the pk. If you already have existing data as foreign key in other tables, i would just make it unique so you don't have to do any data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use composite unique key on `(start_of_week, end_of_week, weekday)` and then do your INSERT/UPDATE queries as usual but with IGNORE keyword.

You will have no duplicates on `start_of_week, end_of_week, weekday` columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `Table` 
ADD UNIQUE (`start_of_week`, `end_of_week`, `weekday`);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored.
>   For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted.
>   With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs.
>   Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Also you may be interested in ODKU: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "but with IGNORE keyword"

Comment: `INSERT INTO table...` - before. `INSERT IGNORE INTO table...` - after

Answer (score 1):

As you did not mention in your post that what do you mean by "no duplicate saved into table", so if you are talking all fields of table then it will not happen as you are using id as auto_increment.

Further you can create a composite unique key combination of fields based on those you want your data unique.

Suppose you don't want duplicate data based on start_of_week and end_of_week then you can create unique key as per below statement-

```
ALTER TABLE mytable add unique key Uk_start_end(start_of_week,end_of_week);
```

Note: But unique index on so many fields and even long fields can create performance issues, so consider it also.

After creating unique index like this, now you can use your insert statement like below, to avoid any error related with duplicate.

```
Insert ignore into (field1,field2,field3) values('val1','val2','val3');
```

Now mysql just ignore if value is duplicate but insert if not duplicate.